# UIView overlaps UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I want to add a `UISegmentControl` on top of a `UIView`.They are siblings of a parent `UIView`.I pull a `UIView` to the canvas from object library first, and then pull a `UISegmentControl` second,but unluckily the first added `UIView` overlaps the `UISegmentControl`. What I want is that `UISegmentControl` is on top of the `UIView`. I mean `UISegmentControl` z-index is higher than the `UIView`.

The following is the screenshot.

[image: screenshot from interface builder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution would be to programmatically send either the `UIView` to the back or the `UISegmentedControl` to the front in `viewWillAppear(animated:)` using  `parentView.bringSubviewToFront(segmentedControl)` or `parentView.sendSubviewToBack(otherView)`. It doesn't solve the issue of the incorrect appearance in your storyboard but it ought to fix the issue once the app is running.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it did work!But I have found that in Document Outline,the view hierachy determines the z-order.When you change the siblings order,the view's z-order is also changed.

Answer (score 0):

1) First reduce the width and height of the overlapping view to understand its location in view hierarchy. Share your view hierarchy here so we can see in detail.

2) Delete everything from storyboard. Add UIView and then add any subviews. These 2 controls should be children of UIView in view hierarchy.